# Trying to optimize my script

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

Hey so i built a script that filters combo lists, it outputs only combos that not repeat itself more than 2 times but its super slow here is my script:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$fileCombo = file("ww.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$output = fopen("workpless.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

//all domains of the entire list
$domains = array();
//only domains that repeat themself less than 2 times
$less = array();

//takes the combo list explode it to domain names
foreach ($fileCombo as $combo) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $combo);
    $email = explode("@", $pieces[0]);
    //import domains to array
    $domains[] = strtolower($email[1]);
}
//count each string in the array
$ac = array_count_values($domains);
//this foreach just filter all the domains that not repeat themself over 2 times
foreach ($ac as $email => $item) {
    if($item <= 2) {
        $less[] = $email;
    }
}

/* this foreach is the one that makes all the trubles,
it takes all the domains that the last foreach filtered 
and its runing it 1 by 1 on the entire combo list to get
the actual combo */

foreach ($less as $find) {
    $matches = array_filter($fileCombo, function($var) use ($find) { return preg_match("/\b$find\b/i", $var); });
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $data = $match . PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($output, $data);
    }
}

fclose($output);
?>
```

pseudocode(the best i can do):

```
file1:
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example1.com:password
exaple@example2.com:password

array "fileCombo" load file1 into the array
splitting each line by ":" so you will get [0]example@example.com, [1]password
splitting value [0] by "@" so you will get [0]example, [1]example.com
putting value [1] into new array called "domains"
counting how many duplicates of each domain
putting all the domains that have less than 2 dupes inside new array that called "less"
runing 1 by 1 each domain in "less" array on "fileCombo" array
if "less" value was found inside "fileCombo" array value Than
write the entire line from "fileCombo" into a text file
```

This script used for big files with 2~5M lines evrey time thats why i need it to be optimized (its fast when u run like 20k lines on it).

Comment: Use a database....

Comment: it will take same time, its not that im using the same list evreytime, ill have to load it into a db and it will take long time too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** To display all related lines for that domain at the cost of more 5 seconds for 1M lines file

Tested on 80,000 lines (40,000 unique lines) - 2.5 MB

```
Memory Usage

69,994,816 bytes
70,246,808 bytes (process)
71,827,456 bytes (process peak)

Execution Time
0.54409 seconds
```

Tested on 1,000,000 lines (500,000 unique lines) - 33 MB

```
Memory Usage

864,805,152 bytes
865,057,144 bytes (process)
866,648,064 bytes (process peak)

Execution Time
8.9173 seconds
```

My test Machine is i7-3612QM (CPU Mark 6833) 4GB RAM SSD

Sample from [80,000 lines file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qahxvjhlh28zrq/ww1.txt?dl=0)

```
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example1.com:password
exaple@example1.com:password
exaple@example1.com:password
exaple@example2.com:password
exaple@example2.com:password
exaple@example3.com:password
exaple@example3.com:password
```

Here is your new version :))

```
<?php
// System Start Time
define('START_TIME', microtime(true));

// System Start Memory
define('START_MEMORY_USAGE', memory_get_usage());

function show_current_stats() {
?>
    <b>Memory Usage</b>
    <pre>
    <?php print number_format(memory_get_usage() - START_MEMORY_USAGE); ?> bytes
    <?php print number_format(memory_get_usage()); ?> bytes (process)
    <?php print number_format(memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE)); ?> bytes (process peak)
    </pre>

    <b>Execution Time</b>
    <pre><?php print round((microtime(true) - START_TIME), 5); ?> seconds</pre>
<?php
}

// Script start here

$fileCombo = file("ww.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$output = fopen("workpless.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

//all domains of the entire list
$domains = array();
//only domains that repeat themself less than 2 times
$less = array();
//let make relateion between domains and its position(keys) in fileCombo
$domains_keys = array();

//takes the combo list explode it to domain names
foreach ($fileCombo as $key => $combo) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $combo);
    $email = explode("@", $pieces[0]);
    //import domains to array
    $domains[] = strtolower($email[1]);

    // check if domain exists or create new domain in $domains_keys array
    if (isset($domains_keys[strtolower($email[1])] )) {
        $domains_keys[strtolower($email[1])][] = $key;
    } else {
        $domains_keys[strtolower($email[1])] = array($key);
    }
}
//count each string in the array
$ac = array_count_values($domains);
//this foreach just filter all the domains that not repeat themself over 2 times
foreach ($ac as $email => $item) {
    if($item <= 2) {
        $less[] = $email;
    }
}

foreach ($less as $find) {
    array_map(function($domain_key) use ($fileCombo, $output) {
        $data = $fileCombo[$domain_key] . PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($output, $data);
    }, $domains_keys[$find]);
}

fclose($output);

// uncomment to show stats : Credit go to micromvc
/* show_current_stats(); */
```

output

```
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example2.com:password
exaple@example2.com:password
exaple@example3.com:password
exaple@example3.com:password
```

Comment: this could work but i need it to output all of the combos(lines) that strpos inside them the list of domains who dosent have more than 2 dupes.

Comment: even thou its only take 1 its super fast thanks alot bro

Comment: don't mention it  :)))

Answer (score 2):

The following should be the most "laconic" solution for your case.
But you should test it on your big files(*2~5M*):

Let's say, `file1.txt` contains these lines:

```
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example.com:password
exaple@example1.com:password
exaple@example2.com:password
```

---

```
$combos = file_get_contents("file1.txt");
preg_match_all("/\b\S+?@(\S+?):\S+?\b/m", $combos, $matches);
$less = array_filter(array_count_values($matches[1]), function ($v){
    return $v <= 2;
});
// $matches[0] - is an array of lines
// $matches[1] - is an array of domains in respective positions as lines
$matched_lines = "";
foreach (array_keys($less) as $domain) {
    $matched_lines .= $matches[0][array_search($domain, $matches[1])] . PHP_EOL;
}
if ($matched_lines) {
    file_put_contents("workpless.txt", $matched_lines, FILE_APPEND);
}
// Now "workpless.txt" contains the following lines:
example@example1.com:password
example@example2.com:password
```

Comment: I love you, it took few min for 1M lines and its realy good for php. thanks alot i apricate it!

Comment: @Marlb0ro, if it works for you, have you tried to accept the answer?